# Elasticsearch mapping for the UK postcodes, able to deal with spacing and capatalization

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am looking for a mapping/analyzer setup for Elasticsearch 7 with the UK postcodes. We do not require any fuzzy operator, but should be able to deal with variance in capital letters and spacing.

Some examples:

**Query string:** "SN13 9ED" should return:

- sn139ed
- SN13 9ED
- Sn13 9ed

but should not return:

- SN13 1EP
- SN131EP

The keyword analyzer is used by default and this seems to be sensitive to spacing issues, but not to capital letters. It also will return a match for `SN13 1EP` unless we specify a query as `SN13 AND 9ED`, which we do not want.

Additionally, with the keyword analyzer, a query of `SN13 9ED` returns a result of `SN13 1EP` with a higher relevance than `SN13 9ED` even though this should be the exact match. Why are 2 matches in the same string a lower relevance than just 1 match?

**Mapping for postal code**

```
"post_code": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
},
```

**Query**

```php
  "query" => array:1 [▼
    "query_string" => array:1 [▼
      "query" => "KT2 7AJ"
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: Could you share your mapping details? Also did you try specifying  `default_operator` as `AND`. Default operator for multi token search for `query_string` is OR, that's why you see other results. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-top-level-params

Comment: Please share your mapping and exact query you are applying on the `postcode` field.

Comment: Hey, I have added the mapping and the query. The query is actually being run through a PHP library so I need to work out how to get the raw, but its actually only using a query string at this stage. I have added the AND default operator and this seems to help. I now get only the correct results within my search.

Comment: I still have the issue with spacing and capitalization though. Would really appreciate any advice on the mapping.

Comment: That's good enough for me. Thanks Adam!! I'll update in a while!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe based on my comments, you may have been able to filter out `SN13 1EP` when your search string would be `SN13 9ED`.

Hope you are aware of what [`Analysis`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html) is, how [`Analyzers`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analyzer-anatomy.html) work on [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) field and how by default [`Standard Analyzer`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) is applied on tokens before they eventually are stored in inverted index. Note that this is only applied on `text` fields.

Looking at your mapping, if you would have used searching on `post_code` and not `post_code.keyword`, I believe capitalization would have been resolved because ES for `text` field by default uses `Standard Analyzer` which means your tokens would eventually gets saved in index in lowercase format and even while querying, ES during querying time, the analyzer would be applied before it searches in the inverted index.

Note that by default, the same analyzer as configured in the mapping are applied during index time as well as search time *on that field*

For the scenarios where you have **`sn131ep`** what I've done is made use of [Pattern Capture Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-capture-tokenfilter.html) where I've specified a regex which would break the token into two of lengths 4 and 3 each and thereby save them in inverted index which in this case would be `sn13` and `1ep`. I'm also lowercasing them before I store them in inverted index.

**Note that the scenario I'm adding for your postcode is that its size is fixed i.e. having 7 characters. You can add more patterns if that is not the case**

Please see below for more details:

### Mapping:

```
PUT my_postcode_index
{
 "settings" : {
    "analysis" : {
       "filter" : {
          "mypattern" : {
             "type" : "pattern_capture",
             "preserve_original" : true,
             "patterns" : [
                "(\\w{4}+)|(\\w{3}+)",             <--- Note this and feel free to add more patterns
                "\\s"                              <--- Filter based on whitespace
             ]
          }
       },
       "analyzer" : {
          "my_analyzer" : {
             "tokenizer" : "pattern",
             "filter" : [ "mypattern", "lowercase" ]   <--- Note the lowercase here
          }
       }
    }
 },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "postcode":{        
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",                 <--- Note this 
        "fields":{
          "keyword":{
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Documents:

```
POST my_postcode_index/_doc/1
{
  "postcode": "SN131EP"
}

POST my_postcode_index/_doc/2
{
  "postcode": "sn13 1EP"
}

POST my_postcode_index/_doc/3
{
  "postcode": "sn131ep"
}
```

Note that these documents are semantically the same.

### Request Query:

```
POST my_postcode_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "postcode",
      "query": "SN13 1EP",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 24,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 3,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 0.6246513,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_postcode_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.6246513,
        "_source" : {
          "postcode" : "SN131EP"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_postcode_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.6246513,
        "_source" : {
          "postcode" : "sn131ep"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_postcode_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.5200585,
        "_source" : {
          "postcode" : "sn13 1EP"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Notice that all three documents are returned even with queries `snp131p` and `snp13 1ep`.

### Additional Note:

You can make use of [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to figure out what tokens are created for a particular text

```
POST my_postcode_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "sn139ed"
}
```

And you can see below what tokens are stored in inverted index.

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "sn139ed",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "sn13",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "9ed",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 7,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

### Also:

You may also want to read about [Ngram Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html). I'd advise you to play around both the solutions and see what best suits your inputs.

Please test it and let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: That is incredibly useful thank you. Can I use this for the other way around also? i.e. if we have `SN13 1EP` stored in the document, but we try to search for `sn131ep`?

Comment: I have added another answer below. I wonder if you can comment on the performance/drawbacks of this option? I think it simply removes all the white space and lower cases the value so we are no longer searching by tokens.

Comment: It would work for `sn131ep` as well. Because by default the analyzer would also get applied while querying time, meaning it would break the token into `sn13 1ep`. Analyzers are applied twice, during indexing and searching as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html). For any field, by default, whatever you configure in mapping, the same analyzer would be applied during both ingesting and querying.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Opsters answer, the following can also be used to tackle the issue from the opposite angle. For Opster's answer, they suggest splitting value by a known postcode pattern, which is great.

If we do not know the pattern, the following can be used:

```
{
  "analysis": {
    "filter": {
      "whitespace_remove": {
        "pattern": " ",
        "type": "pattern_replace",
        "replacement": ""
      }
    },
    "analyzer": {
      "no_space_analyzer": {
        "filter": [
          "lowercase",
          "whitespace_remove"
        ],
        "tokenizer": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
{
  "post_code": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    },
    "analyzer": "no_space_analyzer"
  }
}
```

This allows us to search with any kind of spacing, and with any case due to the lowercase filter.

`sn13 1ep`, `s n 1 3 1 e p`, `sn131ep` will all match against `SN13 1EP`

I think the main drawback to this option, however, is we will no longer get any results for `sn13` as we are not producing at tokens. `sn13*` would bring us back results, however.

Is it possible to mix both of these methods together so we can have the best of both worlds?

Comment: Let me do some more analysis. Turns out that UK postcode has a standard as mentioned in this [link](https://www.mrs.org.uk/pdf/postcodeformat.pdf). I'm trying to see if I can first ensure, that only required tokens are created in indexing time. I don't want to create additional tokens as it can at times, create unnecessary tokens which may never be queried and ends up eating space. I'd rather use the `pattern analyzer` only during search time so that it can create valid tokens and thereby search in ES and return document accordingly, whilst using standard analyzer during indexing time.